Is it safe to eat brassicas that are fertilized using fish waste?
Some Brassica species such as Brassica juncea and Brassica oleracea (broccoli, cabbage, cauliflower, kale, etc.) are hyperaccumulators of heavy metals. If the soil where such plants grow is regularly fertilized using fish waste (guts, skin, heads, bones, etc.), should I avoid eating the plant? Wild fish accumulate heavy metals and I am worried that the heavy metals would make their way into the soil, the plants, and ultimately into my food and body.

I'd get a soil test done if you're worried about it.
